# Solving a simple linear differential equation does not work as advertised

Tags: differential-equations

I have been following examples in an [introduction to *Mathematica*](http://www.wifa.uni-leipzig.de/fileadmin/user_upload/itvwl-vwl/makro/Lehre/ws/bgpe/QDM_Intro_complete.pdf). But the following example regarding a linear differential equation does not work:

```
Clear[a, b]; dex = x'[t] == a + b x[t];
sol = DSolve[dex, x'[t], t]
```

In the tutorial linked above, *Mathematica* gave a closed-form solution, whereas in my experiment, I only got the input echoed back:

```
Out[56] = DSolve[Derivative[1][x][t] == a + b x[t], Derivative[1][x][t], t]
```

It seems that in my case, *Mathematica* (10.0.2) couldn't solve the same differential equation.

Can someone please tell me how to fix the example above?

Thanks.

Comment: Inside the `DSolve` change the `x'[t]` to `x[t]` and try again.

Comment: What Sektor said.  With `DSolve`, the second argument must be the function you're looking to solve for, either with or without its argument.  *It cannot be an expression written in terms of that function*, such as its derivative.  However, with `DSolveValue`, it can. `DSolveValue[dex, x'[t], t]` will first solve for `x`, then substitute the result into `x'[t]`.

Comment: It's a typo in the tutorial.  If you look at the output, it gives a rule for `x[t]`, not for `x'[t]` -- that is, the input and output do not match.  You'll have to ask the author about it.  He would probably appreciate the chance to correct it.  Otherwise, as everyone has said, the input should have had `x[t]`.

Answer (score 3):

Solve for `x[t]`:

```
sol1 = First@DSolve[x'[t] == a + b x[t], x[t], t]
sol2 = First@DSolve[Derivative[1][x][t] == a + b x[t], x[t], t]
ans1 = D[x[t] /. sol1, t]
ans2 = D[x[t] /. sol2, t]
```

[image]